# MailChimp API not displaying all the newsletters

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am using mailchimp to display all the newsletters in my webpage.

Am using this API call to get all newsletters, `https://usX.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/campaigns`

But am only getting 10 campaigns, but there are many more campaigns in the mailchimp account.

Is there anything wrong here?
How can I get all the newsletters or all campaign ids?

Comment: See the documentation [here](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/campaigns/#read-get_campaigns). The default value of the `count` parameter is 10. You're not passing any parameters to the API call, so the default value of the `count` parameter (10) is used and that's why you only get 10 campaigns.

Comment: @ekad this is what I was looking for, you can post as an answer am happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

According to the official documentation of the `/campaigns` endpoint [here](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/campaigns/#read-get_campaigns), there is a `count` parameter that indicates the number of campaign records you want to return. The default value of the `count` parameter is 10. You're not passing any parameters to the `/campaigns` endpoint, so the default value of the `count` parameter (10) is used and that's why you only get 10 campaigns.

You can get all campaigns by making two API calls to the `/campaigns` endpoint. Make the first API call with `count` parameter set to 1. You will get only one campaign, but you will also get `total_items` in the response body. The value of `total_items` shows the total number of campaigns you currently have in your MailChimp account. The second API call should have `count` parameter set to the value of `total_items` obtained from the response of the first API call. You will get all campaigns in the response body of the second API call.